# JOIN query with WHERE clause returns fewer results than expected in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

First query:

```
SELECT 
    TAB1.[CDNO], TAB1.[IDTNO], 
    IIF(ISNULL([TAB1.ECONIV3]), [TAB1.ECONIV2], 'none')  AS [CONTRIB] 
FROM 
    TAB1 
WHERE 
    (TAB1.[UNNN] <> "WATER" AND TAB1.[CCCCPP] <> "SALT") 
;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT 
 TAB1.[CDNO], TAB1.[IDTNO], IIF(ISNULL([TAB1.ECONIV3]), [TAB1.ECONIV2], 'none')  AS [CONTRIB] 
 , IIF(ISNULL([TAB2.ENTCOM3]), [TAB1.ENTCOM2],'none')  AS [CONCOM] , IIF(ISNULL([TAB2.ENTSTI3]), [TAB1.ENTSTI2],'none')  AS [CONSTI] 
 FROM
  TAB1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB2  
  ON (TAB1.[IDTNO] = TAB2.[PTDINO] AND (IIF(ISNULL([TAB1.ECONIV3]), [TAB1.ECONIV2], 'none')  = IIF(ISNULL([TAB2.ENTSTI3]), [TAB1.ENTSTI2],'none'))
  WHERE ( TAB1.[UNNN] <> "WATER" AND TAB1.[CCCCPP] <> "SALT") 
;
```

TAB1 was has 8 times the number of rows of TAB2.
There is something wrong with the second query has it returns less rows than the first query.
So my issue is in the second query where I'm trying to have all the rows of the selected column of TAB1 with in addition the two columns from
TAB2 with a match on the 2 OUTER JOIN conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Second query shouldn't run because it has an odd number of parentheses (meaning you're missing one), based on what you said here is the updated query:

```
SELECT TAB1.[CDNO]
   , TAB1.[IDTNO]
   , IIF(ISNULL([TAB1.ECONIV3]), [TAB1.ECONIV2], 'none')  AS [CONTRIB] 
   , IIF(ISNULL([TAB2.ENTCOM3]), [TAB1.ENTCOM2],'none')  AS [CONCOM] 
   , IIF(ISNULL([TAB2.ENTSTI3]), [TAB1.ENTSTI2],'none')  AS [CONSTI] 
 FROM
  TAB1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TAB2  
  ON (TAB1.[IDTNO] = TAB2.[PTDINO]) AND (IIF(ISNULL([TAB1.ECONIV3]), [TAB1.ECONIV2], 'none')  = IIF(ISNULL([TAB2.ENTSTI3]), [TAB1.ENTSTI2],'none'))
  WHERE ( TAB1.[UNNN] <> "WATER" AND TAB1.[CCCCPP] <> "SALT")
```

By your description my first guess is something is turning the outer join into an inner join, but you don't reference the outer table at all in the where clause. I don't suppose there is any more to the where clause or a group by statement that's not included in the above example?

Comment: Even amount of parentheses opened and closed in the second query, so there may be something else ?

Comment: Yup, has to be something else, but nothing in that query could cause exclusion from the right table, well additional exclusion from the first query anyway, since the where clause references to the right table are the same between the queries.